# What is the exact definition of the for loop in Rust?

Tags: for-loop, reference, iterator, rust

I'm coming from a C (and to a lesser extent, C++) background. I wrote the following code snippet:

```
fn main() {
    let my_array = [1, 2, 3];
    let print_me = |j| println!("= {}", j);
    for k in my_array.iter() {
        print_me(k);
    }
}
```

This compiled and ran as expected, but then I specified the type of the argument passed to the closure `print_me` thus:

```
fn main() {
    let my_array = [1, 2, 3];
    let print_me = |j: i32| println!("= {}", j);
    for k in my_array.iter() {
        print_me(k);
    }
}
```

I got a compilation error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:6:22
  |
6 |             print_me(k);
  |                      ^
  |                      |
  |                      expected i32, found &{integer}
  |                      help: consider dereferencing the borrow: `*k`
  |
  = note: expected type `i32`
             found type `&{integer}`
```

Now this confused me until I changed `k` to `&k` in the `for` statement, which worked fine:

```
fn main() {
    let my_array = [1, 2, 3];
    let print_me = |j: i32| println!("= {}", j);
    for &k in my_array.iter() {
        print_me(k);
    }
}
```

It seems that I misunderstood the `for` syntax itself -- or maybe the exact workings of an iterator -- or maybe the usage syntax of a reference vis-a-vis a pointer [which are related but distinct in C++].

In the construct `for A in B { C1; C2; ... Cn }`, what exactly are `A` and `B` supposed to be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, here's a link to [the definition of `for` in the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#iterator-loops).

To summarise, `B` is any expression which evaluates to something that can be converted into a value that implements the `Iterator<T>` trait, whilst `A` is a *irrefutable pattern* that binds values of type `T`.

In your specific case, [`slice::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) returns an [`Iter<i32>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html), which [implements `Iterator<Item = &i32>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#impl-Iterator). That is, it doesn't yield `i32`s, it yields `&i32`s.

Thus, in both the first and second examples, `k` is actually binding to `&i32`s, not `i32`s.  When you specified the type of the closure, you were actually specifying *the wrong type*.  The reason the final example works is because `A` is a pattern, *not a variable name*.  What `&k` is *actually* doing is "de-structuring" the `&i32`, binding the `i32` part to a variable named `k`.

The "irrefutable" part simply means that the pattern must *always* work.  For example, you can't do `for Some(x) in thingy` where `thingy` implements `Iterator<Option<_>>`; `Some(x)` would not necessarily be valid for every element in the iterator; thus, it's a *refutable pattern*.

Answer (score 6):

Many iterators actually return a *reference* rather than a value. To be sure, you have to check the return type of `.iter()`, which should be of the form `Iterator<Item = X>`: `X` will be the type of the variable returned.

So here:

```
fn main() {
    let my_array = [1, 2, 3];
    let print_me = |j: i32| println!("= {}", j);
    for k in my_array.iter() {
        print_me(k);
    }
}
```

This `X` is `&i32` (a reference to `i32`), and therefore `k` has type `&i32`.

This is why, when calling `print_me`, there is an error: `&i32` is passed where `i32` is expected.

---

There are multiple possible fixes here:

1. specify a different type to `print_me`:

   ```
   let print_me = |j: &i32| println!("= {}", j);
   ```
2. dereference the value of `k`:

   ```
   print_me(*k);
   ```
3. change the type of `k` by *destructuring* in the loop:

   ```
   for &k in my_array.iter() { ... }
   ```

The destructuring occurs because `for .. in` accepts an irrefutable pattern, so you can pattern match like you would do in a `match` expression, except that the variable's type *has* to match (otherwise you get a compiler time error).

To better illustrate it, we can use a slightly more complicated example:

```
fn main() {
    let my_array = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)];
    let print_me = |a: i32, b: i32| println!("= {} {}", a, b);
    for &(j, k) in my_array.iter() {
        print_me(j, k)
    }
}
```

The type of `my_array` is `[(i32, i32)]`: an array of tuples of 2 `i32`. The result of `.iter()` is therefore of type `Iterator<Item = &(i32, i32)>`: an iterator to a reference to a tuple of 2 `i32` aka `&(i32, i32)`.

When we use the irrefutable pattern `&(j, k)` what happens is that we destructure the tuple so that:

- the first element binds to `j` (inferred to be of type `i32`, only works because `i32` is `Copy`)
- the second element binds to `k` ((inferred to be of type `i32`)

`j` and `k` thus become temporary copies of the `i32` inside this element.