# Is there a difference between `for i in &v` and `for i in v`?

Tags: for-loop, rust, reference

I am currently reading [chapter 8 of The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-01-vectors.html), which contains this code:

```
let v = vec![100, 32, 57];
for i in &v {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

I'm not sure why the `&` is necessary in `for i in &v`. I tried removing it and the code still works. Does `for i in v` do the same thing, or is it different somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between iter and into\_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the exact definition of the for loop in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224927/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-the-for-loop-in-rust)

Answer (score 5):

> I'm not sure why the & is necessary in for i in &v. I tried removing it and the code still works. Does for i in v do the same thing, or is it different somehow?

It does something slightly different (or it does the same thing on a different structure, if you prefer). The problem is at chapter 8 you're a bit early for those concepts, especially without knowing your experience with other programming languages.

I would strongly recommend that you keep on reading, and either you'll eventually find out (or understand on your own, I don't remember if it's made explicit) or you can come back to it later.

If it really bothers you, here's my attempt at an explanation:

As in various other programming programming languages, Rust's `for` loop works on arbitrary things which can be iterated (sometimes called "iterables"). In Rust the concept is represented by [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html), aka "things which can be converted into an iterator". Now the "Into" prefix is important because it generally means *consuming conversion* (after [the `Into` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html)). That is,

```rust
let a = thing();
let b = a.into_iter();
// println!("{:?}", a); // probably an error because the previous line "consumed" `a` unless it's trivial and copy
```

So far so good. In one case Rust calls `Vec::into_iter`, and in another case it calls `<&Vec>::into_iter`. With many methods this would make no difference, because only one such method exists. *However*, it does matter for `IntoIterator`, because there exist both

```
impl<T> IntoIterator for Vec<T>
```

and

```
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a Vec<T>
```

Why and what's the difference? Well, above I noted that `IntoIterator` consumes its subject, so the first consumes the `Vec` while the second just... consumes a reference to a `Vec`, which isn't even consuming because references can be copied.

As a result, in the original case you can keep using the `Vec` after having iterated it, but after your modification you can not, because the vector has been consumed and destroyed by the for loop. You can see that by adding

```
println!("{:?}", v);
```

after the loop, [the second one will refuse to build](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=87fdcc5d8bc4f507fa0936dbe852fc75).

There's another consequence to this, which isn't too relevant here but is in other situations: if we look at the declaration of the two implementations more broadly we get this:

```rust
impl<T> IntoIterator for Vec<T> {
    type Item = T;

    [...]
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a Vec<T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    [...]
}
```

The `Item` associated type is different: in the first case, because the vector is consumed the iterator gets to move (and provide) the actual items contained in the collection. In the second case however, since the vector is *not* consumed, the loop can not own the items: that'd be stealing and in Rust you can only steal from corpses. So it can only hand out *references* to the item.

This is mostly relevant for non-`Copy` types (not the case here as integers are `Copy`) as it influences the specific operations you can perform on the items (that is, in your loop).

Comment: "you can only steal from corpses" - sounds like the possibility of use-after-free...

Answer (score 2):

(Please refer to the [other comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61907736/9716597) for details.)

Here's a simpler explanation.

As you learned before in the section [Ways Variables and Data Interact: Move](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#ways-variables-and-data-interact-move), assigning non-[`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#stack-only-data-copy) variables result in a move rather than a copy. For example:

```
let a = String::from("hello");
let b = a;                     // move

println!("{} {}", a, b);       // error: borrow of moved value
```

Similarly, giving a `Vec` to a `for` loop transfers ownership to the loop.  For `Vec`, each of the elements is *moved* into the loop variable, and the `Vec` is no longer accessible after the loop:

```
fn main() {
    // creates a Vec<String>
    let v: Vec<_> = ["a", "b", "c"].iter().copied().map(String::from).collect();

    // elements are moved into s, no clone required
    for s in v {
        println!("{}", s);
    }

    // error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `v`
    // println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0aa5f0a8397f1beb77ce0ae2ed23a515))

Passing a `&Vec` to a `for` loop, on the other hand, assigns the loop variable *references* to the elements, so the variable continues to own the `Vec`:

```
fn main() {
    // creates a Vec<String>
    let v: Vec<_> = ["a", "b", "c"].iter().copied().map(String::from).collect();

    // s is a reference to individual elements
    for s in &v {
        println!("{}", s);
    }

    // v can still be accessed
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a91303b4106a701e014663042825e231))

Note that even though integers are `Copy`, a `Vec` containing them is not.